# how to add transclude in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to add **transclude** property in angularjs .I am got getting error but still  not able to implement the **transclude** property .I am not able to see both content outer and inner contend. I am not able to display both text "hello" and "this" simultaneously

here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/qr45XmP046OCzZPyCeyO?p=preview

```
 var app =angular.module('Testappp',[]);
    app.directive('superMan',function(){

        return {

            restrict:"E",

          //  templateUrl:'template/home.html',
            transclude :true,
            template:"<div ng-transclude>this</div>",





        }

    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so,

```
var app =angular.module('Testappp',[]);

app.directive('superMan', function () {

    return {
        restrict: "E",

        transclude: true,
        template: 
          "<div>" + 
            "<div>this</div>" + 
            "<div ng-transclude></div>" +
          "</div>",
    }

})
```

[`Example`](http://plnkr.co/edit/6mSBOYAKnmNd8UZzb0MV?p=preview)

Your example does not work because as said in documentation about [`ngTransclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)

> Directive that marks the insertion point for the transcluded DOM of
>   the nearest parent directive that uses transclusion.
>   **Any existing content of the element that this directive is placed on
>   will be removed before the transcluded content is inserted**.